# segmentation fault with negative index

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, segmentation-fault

This code fragment gives segfault on the line with ->, please note n=3

```
real_t _b[n+1];
real_t * b = _b+1;
std::fill( b, b + n , (real_t)0.0 );
for ( unsigned c = 0; c < n; c ++ )
  {
->   b[c-1] = 0; b[c] = 1;
     Lsolve( xtmp, lu, b, n );
```

I'm told this is because I'm in 64-bit (Linux amd64, gcc 4.6, debug flag -O0)

anyone could tell me more?

Answer (score 3):

It's to do with the two's complement value of the index being added to the address, it works fine in 32 bit but not 64

Detailed here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/41349

Comment: thanks @tom502, I've changed 'unsigned c' to 'int c', and the problem seems solved :-)